# How to postfix each vocal with "g"+the vocal?

Tags: python

How to produce

`hegellogo wogorld` from `hello world` with list comprehension?

My attempt is not complete as follows.

```
["g"+x for x in "hello world" if (x=="a" or x=="i" or x=="u" or x=="e" or x=="o")]
```

It produces `["ge","go","go"]` instead of `hegellogo wogorld`

Note: I am only interested in list comprehension method.

Comment: Your output is a string so there must be something other than list comprehension...

Comment: Using `re`: `re.sub(r'([aeiou])', r'\1g\1', 'hello world')`

Comment: The first correct answer is accepted for the sake of fairness. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The if clause in the comprehension is filtering it.  We instead want a ternary on whether each character is a vowel or not.  We also need to join the resulting characters back together.

```
phrase = "hello world"
vowels = "aeiou"

''.join(char + "g" + char if char in vowels else char for char in phrase)
```

Answer (score 2):

For each character `ch`, you want your result to include either `ch + 'g' + ch` (if `ch` is a vowel) OTHERWISE just `ch`. You can express that as

```
(ch + 'g' + ch) if ch in "aeiou" else ch
```

So you need something like:

```
''.join([(ch + 'g' + ch) if ch in "aeiou" else ch for ch in "hello world"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks okay to me. An else part is missing and thats what results in unexpected stdout.

```
x = "hello world"
y = "".join(["g"+a if a in ['a','e','i','o','u'] else a for a in x])
y
--> 'hgellgo wgorld'
```